# Composite C1: Cannot save pages after inserting image

Tags: c1-cms

Has anyone had an issue saving pages after they have inserted an image? If I insert an image on a page, I can not save or publish. The save button is enabled, but it does not do anything when I click on it. When I try to change to source view, the application freezes and never shows the source code.

I have another installation of Composite C1 on another server that does not have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by chance running Composite C1 on GoDaddy hosting on their (sitename).previewdns.com setup?

We got a report that GoDaddy will inject custom markup (html that displays a modal window warning that you are on the preview domain) into the responses from the server when you are on the preview domain and this breaks the exact feature in Composite C1 you describe.

If you reference the site using another hostname that does not trigger the GoDaddy "inject some extra markup" feature, you should not experience this error.